# refactor and find solution for get only few item of relation in laravel elequent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the model and also my model is (one to many) (one category has many products) and product have some (one to many) relations so at first, I want to get only categories that have products and after that, I need to get only 6 product's item, so I solve first part but in the second part that I need to get only a few items, I need help. my query is :

```
 $categories_products = Category::with('products.images','products.brand','products.variables')->whereHas('products', function($query){
        $query->where('status', 1);
    })->get();
```

please help me to refactor this code to be more optimize and solve my second problem

Comment: your query looks fine all you need to get `6` product from each category would be like this `$query->where('status', 1)->take(6);`

Comment: that's not working take operation does not any effect on this query!

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit

```
$categories_products = Category::with('products.images','products.brand','products.variables')->whereHas('products', function($query){
            $query->where('status', 1);
        })->limit(6)->get();
```